# How to stop line breaks in textarea with multiple lines ( Text area (multiple rows) )?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have Filed in my content type with widget **Text area (multiple rows)**. when some one paste content into this having line breaks, my requirement is to remove line breaks and save it in single line text.

I have selected **Text processing** as **Plain text**  in filed settings. And in **plain text** format support to convert line breaks into html br tag is not checked.

Please suggest some way to remove line breaks while pasting content into this field.

current:

[image]

Required:

[image]

In short is there any way to **Make textarea to behave like textfiled while saving content** ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check that the field is set to plain text in the "Manage Display" page of your content type.

Comment: Thanks, that I know it will start displaying it into plain text. But I was looking that I can give users multiple lines to enter but that must get saved into filed without line breaks so I did some jqery like this : $("#my-filed").bind('paste', function(e){
        var el = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(el).val($(el).val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," "));
        }, 100);
    });

Comment: When some one past content having line breaks it will be converted into single line by this jQqery code. Is there any other way to achive this ie: without jqery ?

Comment: CSS is an option.. I don't know that much about formats in Drupal. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

Comment: Actually I want to behave textarea like textfiled. so its working fine for me by applying jqery but I was trying to do without jqery in more proper way !